# Refresh state on returning success in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i need a method to refresh a state on some condition. Let's say after adding a new record when i redirected the state on success then it still displays old records and not including the latest record that was just added before redirecting state.
The new record is listed only after refreshing the state.

How can i overcome this silly problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    //use your code inside this
});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for sharing this method. It is working like a charm.